# Заветный селектор в CSS

Tags: css, css3

Современный CSS в том числе и то, что уже есть в версии CSS3 не позволяет мне сделать простой вещи, а именно выбрать внутри родительского элемента (контейнера) `last`/`first`/`n-th-child`'а определенного класса. На ресурсе, где я изучал HTML и CSS способности псевдокласса `last`/`first`/`n-th-child` объяснены на примере со списком однородных элементов (`li` внутри `ul`), но если набор элементов внутри родительского будет неоднородным, к примеру таким:

```html
<div>
  <div></div>
  <a></a>
  <a></a>
</div>
```

То "прицелиться" во вторую ссылку в списке элементов селектором `div a:n-th-child(2)` не получится ибо `last`/`first`/`n-th-child`'ы работают только с общим набором дочерних элементов родителя и понятия не имеют о том, что нам нужно выбрать именно случай когда второй раз в списке встречается именно элемент **нужного класса**, а не просто второй элемент списка.
Увы, указанная тройка псевдоклассов этого не умеет - проверено на собственном опыте.

Как же все таки делать желаемую вышеупомянутую выборку? Существует ли такой селектор/псевдокласс (может он мне просто неизвестен) или же есть обходные пути, к примеру, хитрая комбинация селекторов? Спасибо заранее за ответ.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Очень просто, используйте [nth-of-type(2)](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-of-type.asp) вместо [n-th-child(2)](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp):

```css
div a:nth-of-type(2) {
  color: red;
}
div a:last-of-type {
  color: green;
}
div a:first-of-type {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>1 div</div>
  <a>first link</a>
  <a>2 link</a>
  <a>3 link</a>
  <a>4 link</a>
  <a>last link</a>
  <div>2 div</div>
</div>
```

Оффтоп: не пишите столько текста в вопросе.

Comment: `last` при этом все равно сделать нельзя

Comment: @xaja с чего это вдруг? Обновил ответ. Ссылка – http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_last-of-type.asp

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Мне помогло! Думаю все на этом.

Answer (score 2):

[`nth-of-type`](http://htmlbook.ru/css/nth-of-type) и [`nth-last-of-type`](http://htmlbook.ru/css/nth-last-of-type)
Только подсчёт номера будет осуществляться по тегу, а не по классу.

```css
a, span {
  display: block;
}

span:nth-of-type(3) {
  color: red;
}

.a:nth-of-type(4) { /* 4й элемент каждого тега, если у него есть класс .a */
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<span class="a">S-1 A-1</span>
<a>L-1</a>
<span class="b">S-2 B-1</span>
<a>L-2</a>
<span class="a">S-3 A-2</span>
<a>L-3</a>
<span class="b">S-4 B-2</span>
<a class="a">L-4 A-3</a>
<span>S-5</span>
<a>L-5</a>
```

Comment: А почему по классам нельзя?

Comment: @IngeniousTom, ну не предусмотрели вроде классы. В другом ответе есть ссылка на спецификацию.

Comment: Я только что проделал то же самое с классами

Comment: @IngeniousTom, да, я был неправ, можно.

Comment: не удобства в том что вёрстка должна быть простой , и стили надо придавать без классов иначе при программировании этой вёрстки очень сильно усложнится генерация html .

Comment: @LenovoID, неправда. Хотя что вёрстку переусложнять не следует, согласен.

Comment: @IngeniousTom, и почему зелёным выделен не 4й элемент с классом `a`, а 4я ссылка?